# incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String

Tags: user-interface, junit, junit4

I'm testing my Java project with JUnit using a GUI. An error appears in the `String A = instance.hapus()`.

Can you help me? Thank you very much.

#### Test

```java
@Test
public void hapus()
{
    Minuman instance = new makanan.Minuman();
    String A = instance.hapus();
    assertNull(A);
    // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}
```

#### Method

```java
public void hapus()
{
    String test;
    TotalPrice.setText("");
    panelrequest2.setText(""); 
    txtPotatowadges.setText("");
    txtAyambakar.setText("");
    txtChickenwings.setText("");
    txtGarlicbread.setText("");
    txtCheeseroll.setText("");
    Ayambakarbox.setSelected(false);
    Cheeserollbox.setSelected(false);
    Chickenwingsbox.setSelected(false);
    Garlicbreadbox.setSelected(false);
    Potatowadgesbox.setSelected(false);
}
```

Comment: Hi dinda, welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please add the error you see in the terminal for the line `String A = instance.hapus()`?

Answer (score 0):

Method `hapus` does not return anything so you can not do this:

```java
String A = instance.hapus();
```

If you want to test that it executed properly and not fail just do this:

```java
    @Test
    public void hapus()
    {
        Minuman instance = new makanan.Minuman(); 
        instance.hapus();
        assertTrue(true);
    }
```